# How to display records from a Firebase database using HashMap<String, String>?

Tags: android, firebase, hashmap, firebase-realtime-database, listadapter

I am developing an app in which the users can have multiple lists. My Firebase database looks like this:

[image]

The model that i use is this:

```
public class UserModel {
    private String userId;
    private String userName;
    private String userEmail;
    private HashMap<String, String> lists;

    public UserModel() {}

    public void setUserId(String userId) {this.userId = userId;}
    public String getUserId() {return userId;}

    public void setUserName(String userName) {this.userName = userName;}
    public String getUserName() {return userName;}

    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {this.userEmail = userEmail;}
    public String getUserEmail() {return userEmail;}

    public void setLists(HashMap<String, String> lists) {this.lists = lists;}
    public HashMap<String, String> getLists() {return lists;}
}
```

For displaying the lists, i use a `FirebaseListAdapter` and a `ListView`. If i use the code like this:

```
DatabaseReference listsRef = usersRef.child(userId).child("lists");
adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Map<String, String>>(MainActivity.this, Map.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listsRef) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, Map<String, String> map, int position) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Log.d(TAG, entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }                
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error:(221, 31) error: no suitable constructor found for FirebaseListAdapter
```

All I want to do is to display `the key` and `the value` using `HashMap`. Where am I wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `populateView` is already the value of each index of the list. So you just need to change the `Map` to `String`.

```
adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listsRef) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, String listName, int position) {
        String listKey = this.getRef(position).getKey();
        String listValue = listName;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Actually, you helped me a lot. It's working. If i use `setOnItemClickListener` and i use `adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);` i get the `listName`. Do you have any idea how can i get also from the `adapter` the `listKey`? Thank you so much!

Comment: you can save the `listKey` somewhere on another list variable, then you can retrieve the value anywhere based on position. :) @AlexM.

Comment: "on another list variable", what does it mean? How can i retrieve that value based on position? Thank you again for your answer!

Comment: @AlexM., create a `Map` global variable and then put the `listKey` value based on the position. `listKeys.put(position, listKey);`, call `listKeys.get(position)` to get the key.